# Prevent spamming async API calls from client side?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, express

I'm creating a small multiplayer game were players are allowed to buy cards.

Inside the buy card method I'm doing a series of async requests that check if the user has enough balance, if the game has not started yet etc.

However, when I do this in my console:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    $.post('api/card', {
        game: '53ac5694edd697072c801228'
    }, function (result) {
    console.log(result);
    });
}
```

Users are able to bypass the balance check because when it's still creating the first card the second query has already run and determines the balance is still positive.

What is the best way to prevent this? I'm using Node.js with Express.js

Answer (score 0):

First of all: if they can determine that the balance is still positive then your request handler does things (queries) which are not in transaction. This is the first and the biggest issue. Fix this on the server side. If you are using an SQL database then this will be easy. If you are using non-SQL database then it will be hard since you have to manually implement transactions.

Secondly: you can simply disallow a user to make a second request before completing the first one. This can be easily done by keeping a boolean flag in session and if it is false responding with for example `409 Conflict`. But do this only to improve performance/user experience. Transactions are more important.

Comment: I'm using Mongo and wanted to switch to MySQL anyways. Good time to look into this.

I've already tried your second option, but the requests fired of so fast that the first couple requests didn't contain the boolean yet (so they still continued).

Comment: @Martijn19 Ah, right, there is a race condition on storing data in session as well (unless you use some backend that can do this atomically, I think it can be done with Redis). Well even if you could I would still go for transactions - safer. I advice switching to PostgreSQL. Better then MySQL imho. Also you can do transactions in MongoDB with two phase commits: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/